# Adjust the size of geom_points() in a way they don't overlap

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I'm creating several heatmaps using the following code in r .

```
for(i in 1:length(pdi_levels))   {

p <- ggplot(pdi_tasa_mean_lps_filter %>% filter(inst_finan == pdi_levels[i]), 
            aes(x = emision_mes, y = institucion)) +
     geom_point(size = 10, aes(colour = porcentaje)) +
     geom_text(aes(x = emision_mes, y = institucion, label = porcentaje), color = "white", size = 2) +
     theme_bw() +
     facet_wrap(~emision_anio, scales = "free") +
     scale_color_gradient(low = "pink", high = "red")

print(p)
}
```

Here is an example of my two heat maps.

[image: Heat Maps]

My problem here is that the points(circles) overlap one another, however, if I were to assign to the size argument in the function  `geom_point()`

```
geom_point(size = X, aes(colour = porcentaje))
```

the distance between each main axis, the circles would fit perfectly.

my questions being:

How do I obtain the distance between each main axis?
Is there any other way to make the circles NOT overlap?

the `corrplot` package is NOT an option.

Comment: Check out `geom_quasirandom` from the `ggbeeswarm` package.

Comment: Please add toy data for people interested in experimenting with this.

Comment: You might fix it just by specifying `scale_x_continuous(labels=pretty(data$emision_mes))`